# How to set :user_id with comment notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, notifications, comments

Whenever a notification is created how can we set the `:user_id` for the user who made the comment (and in affect the notification)?

When I check `rails console` for some reason all `Notifications` are showing up as `user_id: 1` when some of them should be `user_id: 2` since the latter was the one who did the commenting.

I'm probably just not understanding the code well enough because I followed along **[this tutorial](http://evanamccullough.com/2014/11/ruby-on-rails-simple-notifications-system-tutorial/)** inputting my own version along the way.

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comment_likes   
  has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true

private

  def create_notification # I replaced the tutorial's "Post" with my "Valuation"
    @valuation = Valuation.find_by(self.valuation_id)
    @user = User.find_by(@valuation.user_id).id
    Notification.create(
     valuation_id: self.valuation_id,
     user_id: @user,
     comment_id: self,
     read: false
    )
  end
end
```

**notifications_controller**

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy]

    def index
    @notifications = Notification.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    @notifications.each do |notification|
        notification.update_attribute(:read, true)
    end
    end


    def destroy
      @notification = Notification.find(params[:id])
      @notification.destroy
      redirect_to :back
    end

private

  def correct_user
    @notification = current_user.notifications.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Not authorized to edit this notification" if @notification.nil?
  end
end
```

**notifications/_notification**

```
<%= link_to Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.name, user_path(Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.id) %> commented on <%= link_to "your value", notification_valuation_path(notification, notification.valuation_id) %>
```

Please let me know if you need further explanation or code to help you help me :-]

Comment: ActiveRecord#reload (In rails console can help http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reload) can help in Rails Console. 
[Off-topic] this tutorial is very bad. IMHO this is better alternative http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity

Comment: I'm not sure but i think if you use `@user = current_user` on your comment.rb, it should fix the problem. `User.find_by(@valuation.user_id).id` finds who made the Valuation...

Comment: Sorry @pauloancheta are you saying `@user = current_user.find_by(@valuation.user_id).id` because that's giving an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
@valuation = Valuation.find_by(self.valuation_id)
@user = User.find_by(@valuation.user_id).id

Notification.create(
     valuation_id: self.valuation_id,
     user_id: @user,
     comment_id: self,
     read: false
    )
```

should be

```
self.notifications.create(
  valuation: self.valuation,
  user: self.valuation.user
)
```

in your migration file set:

```
t.boolean read, default: false
```

in your controller:

```
def index
  @notifications = Notification.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  @notifications.each do |notification|
    notification.update_attribute(:read, true)
  end
end
```

becomes:

```
def index
  @notifications = current_user.notifications
  @notifications.each do |notification|
    notification.update_attribute(:read, true) 
  end
end
```